# Create folder in explicit directory AIR

Tags: file, actionscript-3, air

Like the title says I want to create a folder in a specific directory with Adobe Air.
If I use static methods of File like File.userDirectory works fine but I need to give the choice to select the directory.
I am trying this:

```
file.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, dirSelected); 
file.browseForDirectory("Select a directory"); 

function dirSelected(e:Event):void { 
            trace(file.nativePath); 
            file.resolvePath("new_folder");
            file.createDirectory();
    }
```

Nothing happens

Comment: When you say nothing happens, does that mean there is no error, but also no directory created? Do you get your trace statement?

Comment: Thats right. I get trace statement, no errors and no directory created.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

"resolvePath: Creates a new File object with a path relative to this File object's path, based on the path parameter (a string)."

So:

```
var newDir:File = file.resolvePath("new_folder");
newDir.createDirectory();
```